# Cannot run R from terminal after upgrading to macOS Sierra

Tags: r, terminal

I recently updated my macbook to macOS Sierra (Version 10.12.3 (16D32)), and I am no longer able to run R directly from Terminal:

```
DN51ssqi:~ kjytay$ R
-bash: R: command not found
DN51ssqi:~ kjytay$ R --version
-bash: R: command not found
```

Opening R from the Applications folder or from RStudio works fine. Anyone experience this issue/has been able to fix it?

Here is my R version information:

```
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin13.4.0                
system         x86_64, darwin13.4.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          3.2                         
year           2016                        
month          10                          
day            31                          
svn rev        71607                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
nickname       Sincere Pumpkin Patch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess, but I'm thinking this is probably an issue with your `PATH` settings, which might have been overwritten when you upgraded*. Seems worth a try at least. This is from the RStudio support pages**:

> **R from source (including MacPorts and Homebrew)**
>
> When R is installed from CRAN on OS X the R executable is installed at
>   /usr/bin/R. However, if R is installed directly from source or via a
>   package manager like MacPorts or Homebrew, then the R executable is
>   installed to either /usr/local/bin/R (Homebrew) or /opt/local/bin/R
>   (MacPorts). In order to support these variations, RStudio scans for
>   the R executable in the following sequence:
>
> /usr/bin/R
>   /usr/local/bin/R
>   /opt/local/bin/R
>
> If RStudio is not able to locate R by scanning these locations, it
>   will fall back to using whatever version of R is located at
>   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.

If RStudio is finding R OK, then you must have it at one of these locations. Make sure these locations are in your $PATH list:

In the Terminal:

```
echo $PATH
```

Will display your current PATHs list. If any of the locations in the RStudio quote are missing, you can see if that's where `R` is located by trying to specify that location. For example:

```
/usr/local/bin/R
```

If that works to start R, just add that location to your PATHs list:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

So that OSX knows where to find it!

* It's been noted elsewhere that `homebrew` breaks, for example, on upgrade to Sierra. Here's a blog post outlining some steps an `R` user might like to take after the upgrade: http://www.statsblogs.com/2017/01/26/upgrading-to-macos-sierra-nee-osx-for-r-users/

** Here's the support page where the quote is from https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Using-Different-Versions-of-R

Comment: Thanks lots! adding the location of R to $PATH worked. looks like the previous $PATH value was overwritten by the upgrade.

Comment: I'm glad it helped @kjytay . If it answered your question, I'd appreciate if you'd mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: It seemed that export PATH=$PATH:... only changed the PATH for that particular session. Adding that line to .bash_profile did the trick.