# Setting up macOS terminal to start a non-Anaconda R installation?

Tags: r, bash, terminal, jupyter-notebook

I'm actually trying to get R work with the Jupyter notebook. For this the IRkernel is the native kernel but I'm getting an error code 127 when executing the [last step](https://irkernel.github.io/installation/%22last%20step%22). This is because the last command `IRkernel::installspec()` needs to be run in bash but the terminal is not recognising a [valid PATH to a R installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41951145/cannot-run-r-from-terminal-after-upgrading-to-macos-sierra).

Now, I also have Anaconda installed and despite providing the terminal a valid path to R, keying-in 'R' in the terminal returns this error:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ Shiv$ R
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libintl.9.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/Shiv/anaconda3/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib
Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Which I believe its pointing out to my Anaconda libraries that doesn't have RStudio installed. Now, I would like to keep R as a totally separate tool and not as a part of Conda. What am I missing here that bash won't start R in the native shell? Once am through with it, installing the kernel to work with Jupyter is a tiny process.

Comment: The `@rpath` looks like a bug, but I don't know anything about how R tries to run itself. Can you find a file called `libint.9.dylib` and add its path to your `DL_LOAD_PATH`?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42080325/rp2-missing-libintl-9-dylib-library

Comment: Certainly is related. Could not find the file myself. But why wouldn't bash run R despite a valid PATH?

Comment: The error message means that the R library in turn wants to load (what appears to be) a GetText library (this is related to internationalization support -- display "open file" in the user's preferred language instead of hard-coding it) and not being able to find it.

Comment: More googling also finds me https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1614

Comment: Strange. I do not even have R essentials installed for Anaconda. Gonna raise an issue at IRkernel github.